# "Back to Top" button for Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

How can I create a "back to top" button using a `FloatingActionButton`?

Comment: "I have tried looking all over google": No you didn't. Not only that that's practically impossible, but also a simple search like: "Android scroll to top" yields the solution youre looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `ScrollView` to host your content, you can use [`scrollTo(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int))

```
myFAB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Where `myFAB` is your floating action button and `myScrollView` is your scroll view. This will return your `ScrollView` back to the top left. If you want a scroll animation instead of jumping straight up, use [`smoothScrollTo(int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo(int,%20int)) instead.